# cypress unable to clear localstorage object

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am performing some cypress tests, I want to clear all of the localStorage, but this second object 'https://app.usercentrics.eu' used for saving "User consent choices" can't be cleared by using `cy.clearLocalStorage()` `localStorage.clear()` or `localStorage.removeItem()`
[image: localStorage screen capture]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and have an idea on how to deal with this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying the same thing on the previous question, i.e to get the consent button to show consistently for each test run.

This seems to work,

```js
cy.origin('https://app.usercentrics.eu', () => {
  localStorage.clear();
})
cy.visit('https://www.deepskydata.com/')

cy.get('#usercentrics-root')
  .shadow()
  .find('[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')
  .click()
```

I also start the test with `cy.viewport(1000,4800)` which makes it easier to see the button appearing at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned functions I believe are specific to the domain you are currently in. In order to clear another domain's localStorage, you'd have to switch to that domain

```js
cy.visit('/mySite').clearLocalStorage()
  .visit('/otherDomain').clearLocalStorage();
```

If you find yourself using this often, consider adding it as a Cypress custom command.

Comment: In theory, this should work, but the site gives a 403 forbidden code, which makes sense since it's a consent management website.

Comment: Would adding `{failOnStatusCode: false}` to your second visit still fix the issue? `cy.visit('/otherDomain', { failOnStatusCode: false });`?

Comment: Yes, that solves it but there's an issue that the content-type of the page is 'application/xml' which is not supported by cypress.